# Converting SMS encoding to UTF-8 in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, sms, smpp, 7-bit

I wrote an SMPP Server Transceiver in PHP.
I get this SMS string from my SMPP. It's a UTF8 message which is actually at 7Bit. Here is a sample message:

```
  5d30205d30205d3
```

I know how to convert it. It should be:

```
  \x5d3\x020\x5d3\x020\x5d3
```

I don't want to write it myself. I guess there is already a function that does that for me. Some hidden iconv or using pack() / unpack() to convert this string to the correct format.

I am trying to achieve this using PHP.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599/reliable-sms-unicode-gsm-encoding-in-php

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :

```
$message = "5d30205d30205d3";
echo "\x".implode("\x", str_split($message, 3));
// \x5d3\x020\x5d3\x020\x5d3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i used eventually:

```
public static function sms__from_unicode($message)
{
    $org_msg = str_split(strtolower($message), 3);
    for($i = 0;$i < count($org_msg); $i++)
        $org_msg[$i] = "\u0{$org_msg[$i]}";

    $str = implode(null, $org_msg);
    $str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $str);    
    return $str;
}   

function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
     return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}
```

10x. all.