# sample code to send sms through gsm

Tags: php, gsm

i want to develop php application to send SMS through GSM modem in ubuntu os , i need a working sample code to connect successfully to the GSM modem and send messages through it .i tried some but it dint work.pls help me

thanks in advance

Comment: show your code so that we can find the problem

Comment: I don't think that PHP can do that, you may try with C

Comment: it is possible with php @JasonOOO

Comment: Look at the questions on the right hand side of your screen, especially this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599/reliable-sms-unicode-gsm-encoding-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

you first of all have to show your code before others could help.
download headwind gsm drive. then user the code below

```
$body="";
```

$addr=telephone;
$hgsmdrv = new COM("HeadwindGSM.SMSDriver") or die("Unable to open Headwind GSM Modem Driver");
    // Connect to GSM modem

```
$hgsmdrv->Connect();
// Create message
$sms = new COM("HeadwindGSM.SMSMessage") or die("Unable to create SMS message");
$sms->To = $addr;
$sms->Body = $body;
// Send message
$sms->Send();
//free the objects
$hgsmdrv = null;
$sms = null;
```

hope that helps